# Password protected html messages on a django app

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how do I protected a page with just a passcode using the django web framework . Example, I send a link to an user and in that link there is a message. When the user open the page a passcode field would appear and then when the user type the right passcode, the message will appear. I don't want the user to type an username and password. I just want then to type a 4 digit code.

Comment: I didn't quiet get you. U want a user to enter a passcode and verify him against it? Then where are you stuck? I mean you can ask the user to enter the passcode and access it back right?

Comment: Let say I send you a link and I Tell you, the passcode is 7878. You click the link then you will type 7878 to authenticate and see the message.

Comment: Got that, I understand how to ask user to enter a passcode. But, what is with protected html and where are you actually finding a problem, that u feel, you are not able authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service that returns messages when you send the code via post. This is mostly javascript except for the service that would be handled in your django view.

Check link -> get html + js -> send post with the code -> get the message.